# How to make scripts continue even if an in-built function (eg. dlmread()) fails?

Tags: database, matlab, import

I need to read a lot of data from .txt files using `dlmread` which works fine in 80% cases the problem is for the 20% which are not in the general rule and dlm read fails due to random occurrences of unexpected data(mostly multiple header-lines (strings) present in row).

What I need is a way to still make my script run by skipping the file if dlmread fails (like by storing some boolean variable that would let me know it has failed) 
OR
another more generalised function in MATLAB that I can run to read the data and automate it anyway.

If you can even partially solve my problem it would be of great help.

PS: For some cases the row numbers are predictable where the header lines are present.
also I have tried importdata but it takes too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a function that potentially errors, and you want to simply skip it if it does, you should use the keyword [`try`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) (and possibly `catch`). It's sort of like an `if / else` except that it doesn't crash if a function errors.

```
try
dlmdata = dlmread('Invalid call')  % Will crash
catch
dlmdata = 0; 
warning('Call to dlmread failed')
end

Warning: Call to dlmread failed
```

Note that you don't need the `catch` part, but it's good practice. It's often needed to assign a value to variables, in order to avoid `"Undefined function or variable 'dlmdata'"`.

Comment: Maan I think you just made my day, will take some time for me to confirm but it looks legit thanks a million.